# Does Elastic Load Balancer use nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, elastic-load-balancer

I am trying to configure an Elastic Load Balancer to support websockets. I see several things (e.g. [one](https://mitchellsimoens.com/websockets-behind-elastic-beanstalk/), [two](http://blog.seafuj.com/using-elb-with-websockets), [three](https://www.built.io/blog/websockets-on-aws-s-elb)) telling me to configure it using some nginx configuration. But this is confusing, because nowhere in the ELB documentation does it mention nginx. Where is the official documentation for configuring Elastic Load Balancer using an nginx configuration file?

Comment: You cannot configure an ELB using an nginx configuration file.

Comment: @jbird then what is this article talking about? https://mitchellsimoens.com/websockets-behind-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: @jameshfisher that blog post was written by someone who thinks the ELB abbreviation stands for ELastic Beanstalk. It's really frustrating when people use ELB or EBS abbreviations for Elastic Beanstalk, because it makes everything they write confusing to read.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Load Balancer to Application Load Balancer as Application Load Balancer is a new product of AWS which supports Web Sockets. As Classic Load Balancer do not support Websockets and you have to apply work arounds for them to support Websockets.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/